# Powershell select-string usage

Tags: powershell-3.0

This is my script that removes any lines that contain `/>` in it. I have a new requirement which is to leave all lines that have `index="1"/>`.

Example of the full line I want to leave is `<LOTLEVEL index="1"/>`.  Logic would be, If line contains `index="1"/>` leave the line, if line contains `/>` but not `index="1"/>` remove the line.

Existing scripts looks like this.  Any suggestions would be great.  The simpler the better.

```
$SourceDir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
Get-Content "$SourceDir\*.txt" | Select-String -pattern '/>' -notmatch -pattern | foreach {$_.Line} | out-file "$SourceDir\clean.xml" -encoding ascii -width 1000
```

Comment: Please edit your actual question to include the corrected post, rather than embed it in a comment. Readers will see the question long before they look at the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Get-Content "$SourceDir\*.txt" | where {$_ -notmatch '"/>'} | Select-String '/>'
```

If you need something a little more specific try:

```
Get-Content "$SourceDir\*.txt" | where {$_ -notmatch 'index="\d"(\s+)?/>'} | Select-String '/>'
```